# How to open file and append a string in it, swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to append a string into text file. I am using the following code.

```
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
if (dirs) != nil {
    let dir = dirs![0] //documents directory
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("votes")
    let text = "some text"

    //writing
    text.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    //reading
    let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    println(text2) //prints some text
}
```

this does not append the string to file. Even if I call this function repeatedly.

Comment: That error parameter can come in handy in some cases

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to be able to control whether to append or not, consider using `OutputStream`. For example:

```swift
do {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("votes.txt")
    
    guard let outputStream = OutputStream(url: fileURL, append: true) else {
        print("Unable to open file")
        return
    }

    outputStream.open()
    let text = "some text\n"
    try outputStream.write(text)
    outputStream.close()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

By the way, this is an extension that lets you easily write a `String` (or `Data`) to an `OutputStream`:

```swift
extension OutputStream {
    enum OutputStreamError: Error {
        case stringConversionFailure
        case bufferFailure
        case writeFailure
    }

    /// Write `String` to `OutputStream`
    ///
    /// - parameter string:                The `String` to write.
    /// - parameter encoding:              The `String.Encoding` to use when writing the string. This will default to `.utf8`.
    /// - parameter allowLossyConversion:  Whether to permit lossy conversion when writing the string. Defaults to `false`.

    func write(_ string: String, encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8, allowLossyConversion: Bool = false) throws {
        guard let data = string.data(using: encoding, allowLossyConversion: allowLossyConversion) else {
            throw OutputStreamError.stringConversionFailure
        }
        try write(data)
    }

    /// Write `Data` to `OutputStream`
    ///
    /// - parameter data:                  The `Data` to write.

    func write(_ data: Data) throws {
        try data.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws in
            guard var pointer = buffer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
                throw OutputStreamError.bufferFailure
            }

            var bytesRemaining = buffer.count

            while bytesRemaining > 0 {
                let bytesWritten = write(pointer, maxLength: bytesRemaining)
                if bytesWritten < 0 {
                    throw OutputStreamError.writeFailure
                }

                bytesRemaining -= bytesWritten
                pointer += bytesWritten
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26992040/9) of this answer.

Comment: when I try to read the file it gives nil using `let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        println(text2)`

Comment: Did you definitely `open` the `NSOutputStream` before trying to `write` to it? The `write` will fail if you don't. Also, did you definitely `close` the `NSOutputStream` before trying to read the file in again? You have to close the file before you try to use it again. If you're still having problems, try checking the return value of the `write` function and see if that succeeded or not.

Comment: the `write` function ask me to enter `maxLength`. what should I put there?

Comment: yes I have opened and closed the `NSOutputStream ` before writing and reading respectively

Comment: You shouldn't have a `maxLength` parameter. That means you're calling the wrong rendition of `write` function. Did you include the `extension` I supplied in my answer?

Comment: Yes I was using the wrong one, now included your extension, but still getting `nil`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65136/discussion-between-rob-and-atif-farrukh).

Comment: OMG, need swift 2 version of this!!1

Comment: @Quadrivium - The extension is Swift 2 ready. The only thing that's different is the process of building the path. See revised answer.

Comment: I was using a filename format string with '/' in it... oops  change them to '-'

Comment: Can anyone update for Swift 3? This was a useful extension

Comment: @JohnV - Added Swift 3 rendition.

Comment: maybe some idea how to apply this code with swift 3 ?

Comment: The code in his answer _is_ Swift 3. I added Swift 2 rendition at the end for 2.3 users, but the answer is otherwise Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [FileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) to append String to your text file.  If you just want to append your string the end of your text file just call [seekToEndOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) method, write your string data and just close it when you are done:

---

**FileHandle usage Swift 3 or Later**

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

// create a new text file at your documents directory or use an existing text file resource url
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("simpleText.txt")
do {
    try Data("Hello World\n".utf8).write(to: fileURL)
} catch {
    print(error) 
}
// open your text file and set the file pointer at the end of it
do {
    let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
    fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
    // convert your string to data or load it from another resource
    let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\n"
    let textData = Data(str.utf8)
    // append your text to your text file
    fileHandle.write(textData)
    // close it when done
    fileHandle.closeFile()
    // testing/reading the file edited
    if let text = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(text)  // "Hello World\nLine 1\nLine 2\n\n"
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code as its working for me. Just Add the code as it is:

```
let theDocumetFolderSavingFiles = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filePath = "/theUserData.txt"
let thePathToFile = theDocumetFolderSavingFiles.stringByAppendingString(filePath)
let theFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if(theFileManager.fileExistsAtPath(thePathToFile)){

        do {

            let stringToStore = "Hello working fine"
            try stringToStore.writeToFile(thePathToFile, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("we are geting exception\(error.domain)")
        }

        do{
            let fetchResult = try NSString(contentsOfFile: thePathToFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("The Result is:-- \(fetchResult)")
        }catch let errorFound as NSError{
            print("\(errorFound)")
        }

    }else
    {
        // Code to Delete file if existing
        do{
            try theFileManager.removeItemAtPath(thePathToFile)
        }catch let erorFound as NSError{
            print(erorFound)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that works for me.  UPDATE, it looks like I must have gotten this from here, so credit where credit is due:
[Append text or data to text file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift)

Usage:

```
"Hello, world".appendToURL(fileURL: url)
```

Code:

```
extension String {
    func appendToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        try data.append(fileURL: fileURL)
    }
}

extension Data {
    func append(fileURL: URL) throws {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
            defer {
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(self)
        }
        else {
            try write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the reading part.

The method `cotentsOfFile:` is a method of `NSString` class. And you have use it wrong way.

So replace this line

```
let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Here you have to use `NSString` instead of `String` class.

```
let text2 = NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```