# Apple Swift file write buffer flush

Tags: swift2

I'm following previous advice to write to a file in Xcode 7 with Swift 2, e.g.

```
let loopOmega = "      endloop"
try loopOmega.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let facetOmega = "   endfacet"
try facetOmega.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

When I track down the file in the simulator's file space, I see only the final line, which makes me think that the buffer is getting overwritten, as opposed to going to the file.  How can I flush the buffer with each line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text or data to text file in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift)

Comment: Because I'm trying to create and look at files in an iOS Simulator, I ended up modifying the suggestions, but got it to work!  Thank you.