# Writing to text file in swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios10, writetofile

I am trying to write data that is inputted by a user via `UITextField` to a text file. I am successfully able to do this by the code I have written below. However, when I tried to save more data it will replace the existing data in the textfile with the new data that is being saved. for example, if I save the string 'hello world' and then save another string saying 'bye'. I will only see the string 'bye' in the textfile. Is there a way I can modify my code so I can see 'hello world' on one line of the textile and 'bye' on another.

```
@IBAction func btnclicked(_ sender: Any) {        
   self.savedata(value: answer.text!)
}

func savedata (value: String){    
   let fileName = "Test"
   let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

   let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
   print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")

   let writeString = NSString(string: answer.text!)
   do {
      // Write to the file
      try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
   } catch let error as NSError {
         print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use NSFileHandle, it can seek to the end of the file

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example using `FIleHandler`, adapted to **Swift 3**, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327385/554203) (of course you should add all the error handling code that's missing in my example) :

```
let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first!
let fileurl =  dir.appendingPathComponent("log.txt")

let string = "\(NSDate())\n"
let data = string.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
    if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileurl) {
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(data)
        fileHandle.closeFile()
    }
} else {
    try! data.write(to: fileurl, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 do { 
       let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo:pathWithFileName)
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        let oldData = try String(contentsOf: pathWithFileName,encoding: .utf8).data(using: .utf8)!
         var data = periodValue.data(using: .utf8)!
         fileHandle.write(data)
         fileHandle.closeFile()
         } catch {
            print("Error writing to file \(error)")
         }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Swift 4 version as an extension to String.

```
extension String {

func writeToFile(fileName: String) {
    guard let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
    }

    let fileUrl = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return
    }

    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) else {
        try? data.write(to: fileUrl, options: .atomic)
        return
    }

    if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileUrl) {
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(data)
        fileHandle.closeFile()
    }
}
```

}