# Text not being written to file using String's "write" instance method

Tags: ios, swift

```
var file = ""
var text = ""
var path: URL?

override viewDidLoad(){

  super.viewDidLoad()


    file = "test2.csv" //this is the file I will write to 
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        do {
            text = "Hello"
            try text.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}

    }

   getInsightResult()
}
```

This piece of code is writing "Hello" to "test2.csv" perfectly in my viewDidLoad() method. However, when I run that excerpt of code in a separate method called getInsightResult(), which I call in viewDidLoad, the text that is being written is blank. However, when I print out the text it is not empty, but displays the correct text.

```
 func getInsightResult() {

      for x in 0...4{
          for y in 0...4{
                if(y != 3){
                      do{

                       let temp = arrayOfDataArrays[y]
                       text = String(temp[x])
                       print("Tester:\(temp[x])")
                       print("Text:" + text)

                       try text.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                        }
                       catch {/* error handling here */}
                            }

                          }
                       text = "\n"
                       do{try text.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)}
                       catch {/* error handling here */}

                    }

       }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift for info on appending text to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is merely a misconception on your part: you seem to imagine that String's `write` method *appends* to an existing file, and it doesn't. It replaces the contents of the file.

Your code is thus working perfectly. The text *is* being written to the file, every time you say `text.write...`. The "problem" is that this line:

```
text = "\n"
do{try text.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)}
```

...replaces everything in the file with a single linefeed. And since that is the last line executed, that is the state of the file when we finish.

Comment: Is there a way to append to an existing file? That is what I am trying to do, ultimately

Comment: Sure, just search on "iOS text file append" or similar.

Comment: Or accumulate everything into a string and then write that string out, once. Instead of setting `text` every time, append to `text` every time; then write `text` to a file, once, at the very end.

Comment: Well, I am trying to format my CSV file in a specific way and appending to the `text` string will be complicated.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
let file = "file.txt"
let text = "text content"

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
    do {
        try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what was wrong with the code in the question and explain how your answer solves the problem.