# Saving to defined file multiple times without overwriting previous data

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode10.2

I am trying to create a simple text input application in Swift, which this is my very first application created in this particular language. I am able to create a file and save text to it. The quest that I am on now to find an answer is the following:

How do I save multiple entries from my NSTextField to the same file with a time stamp of the entry? Because every time I hit save, it overwrites the file with the new entry.

The following is my code:

```
    @IBAction func saveTaskButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    //save task function
    do {
        // get the documents folder url
        if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            // create the destination url for the text file to be saved
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("msrfile.txt")
            // define the string/text to be saved
            let text = taskEntry.stringValue
            // writing to disk
            // Note: if you set atomically to true it will overwrite the file if it exists without a warning
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            print("saving was successful")
            // any posterior code goes here
            // reading from disk
            let savedText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            print("savedText:", savedText)   // "Hello World !!!\n"
        }
    } catch {
        print("error:", error)
    }
}
```

**Edit (Found solution):**

The following is my updated code

```
    @IBAction func saveTaskButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    //save task function
    do {
        // get the documents folder url
        if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            // create the destination url for the text file to be saved
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("msrfile.txt")
            // define the string/text to be saved
            let text = taskEntry.stringValue + " " + dateOfTaskEntry.stringValue + "\n"
            let encoding = String.Encoding.utf8

            guard let data = text.data(using: encoding) else {
                throw FileWriteError.convertToDataIssue
            }
            if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                fileHandle.write(data)
            } else {
                try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: encoding)
            }
            print("saving was successful")
            // any posterior code goes here
            // reading from disk
            let savedText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            print("savedText:", savedText)   // "Hello World !!!\n"
        }
    } catch {
     print("error:", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider to use a serializable text format like Property List or JSON to be able to save timestamp and text separately in a collection type or custom struct.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift

Comment: I should have stated that the link you shared is the original post where I found this solution. But it is overwriting when I try and add new text to it

Comment: [link to my code](https://github.com/granticusmaximus/TaskTracker) if you want to take a look at it and run the app on your desktop to see.