# convert JSON Dictionary to Exiting JSON File Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am trying to add json to existing JSON file. json is added to file but it removes the existing json data. I tried everything but its not working for me.

[image]

```
   let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "menu", ofType: "json")!
    print(path)
    ///geting existing json file
    let dataFromFile = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let jsonData = try! JSON(data: dataFromFile!)

    var data: [JSON] = []

    let dataDic =  ["name": "Biryani", "Price": "24", "menuType":"Mains","logo" : "mains1"]
    print(dataDic)
    var newitemjson = JSON(dataDic)
    data = [newitemjson]
    data = data + jsonData["Mains"].arrayValue
    print(data)
    let str = data.description
      let saveData = str.data(using: .utf8)!

     if let file = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath:path) {
          //  let rawData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newitemjson, options: .prettyPrinted)
            file.write(saveData)
            }
```

Comment: Don't post images of code or data, post it as text instead. Besides that it looks to me like you are trying to write to the main bundle which isn't allowed.

Comment: i was trying to add json syntax but its saying format is not correct because   i don't know how to add json in stackoverflow, so i used image

Comment: its is allowed but the issue is when i write data it replaces the with json file data and  removes old data from json

Comment: i want to append dictOBject to existing json object in json file

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327385/11760652) might help. Note that simply appending would leave you with content in the [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format.