# How can I redirect the output of a macOS playground to a file

Tags: swift, macos

I have a simple Swift program running in a macOS playground in Xcode. This displays its output from print statements in the debug area on the Mac screen. Is there some simple method with which I can redirect this output into a file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append text or data to text file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift)

Comment: Writing to a file is trivial. The question is exactly what you mean by “redirect this output”. Are you willing to change the print statements? Or were you hoping that `print` would magically change its meaning?

Comment: @matt, I had hoped that print had a parameter like to: which would allow you to write to an open file but it doesn't as far as I know. What was in my mind was that at the Unix level redirecting stdout is easy without changing the program and I hoped there was some way to access something like that from Swift. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It does! If you're willing to change the print statements, you can add a `to:` parameter. You need an output stream that appends to a file.

Comment: Okay, so https://nshipster.com/textoutputstream/

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, thanks. The suggestion seems quite complicated and I must admit not having understood it all. However, the workaround suggested by Sweeper did produce the result I wanted, though it meant using the CLI rather than doing everything in the playground. So I have gone that way for now.

Comment: @matt, wow! That seems to do just what I want. I hadn't found the version of print with the to: parameter. However, I'm going to have to read your blog a few more times before the stream idea really sinks into my head and I can try it in my playground. It does though confirm my trust that Swift would support something like this. Thanks again.

Comment: Not my blog, it's a different Matt! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the code, you can run the `Contents.swift` file in the playground using the `swift` command in Terminal.app, and use `>` to direct the output to a file, e.g.:

```
swift YourPlayground.playground/Contents.swift > output.txt
```

This will cause the output to be written to `output.txt` in the working directory.

If you *can* change the print statements, you can pass your own implementation of `TextOutputStream` (which writes to a file) to the `to:` parameter of `print`. For more info, see [this link](https://nshipster.com/textoutputstream/#writing-output-to-a-file).

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. That did allow me to create a file as the program's output. It is a fine workaround (and Contents.swift is also useful for saving the playground code as a file), though I had hoped to be able to write the file directly from the playground.

Comment: @espri It appears that I completely misunderstood your question! I thought you didn't want to change the code! Oh well, it seems like matt's link has helped you anyway.

Comment: no problem. I found your suggestion useful and was also happy to learn about Contents.swift. Where does that come from?

Comment: @espri The `.playground` "file" that Xcode creates is not actually a file. It's actually a directory containing (among other things) a `Contents.swift` file. And when you edit the playground's source code, you are actually editing `Contents.swift`.