# Writing Log Text File-Should I create an Array to store Filenames or Keep the File Open

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I want to write a Log File containing the names of all Files processed by the program.Im wondering what will be the right approach to do this

1.Array-Should I store the filenames in a string array and later write the array to text file.Will this result in memory wastage?

2.The second approach would be to create a file and keep the pointer to it open and write the result to it directly without using an intermediate array.But I don't know how to do this.

Currently I'm writing the file using

```
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    //writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}

    //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

***UPDATE:***

As per @Martin 's comment I have followed the following approach.But I'm getting some random characters in the output file

```
  //--------------Setting Up Logging and FileStream
       let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
        let logstream = OutputStream(url: fileURL, append: true)
        logstream?.open()
 //-------------------------------------
   writelog(stream: (logstream)!, fname: x.path)
   logstream.close()
 ----------------------------------
```

WriteLog Function

```
func writelog(stream:OutputStream,fname:String)
    {
        let text = fname
        let bytesWritten = stream.write(text, maxLength: 100)
        if bytesWritten < 0 { print("write failure") }
    }
```

Output:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/file1.jpg≠æ≠ﬁﬁ¿›∫ÄZ+Ä`XTUM/Users/me/Desktop/file2.jpg≠æ≠ﬁﬁ¿›∫Ä+JÄ`6@ø/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpgÄˇˇˇˇˇˇÿ©ÔÕ´âˇˇˇˇ¿3©
```

Note: I had to set the `Max Length` attribute to 100 as the argument was required by the write function to work.

Comment: Don’t store the file name store the resource url.

Comment: Btw you should use a plist file to store your urls

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm referring to storing user readable text files .

Comment: What difference does it make the kind of file the url points to? You need to create an array with your urls and use NSKeyedArchiever to convert your array to data (property list file) and write your data (plist file) to disk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989493/how-to-open-file-and-append-a-string-in-it-swift shows how to *append* to an existing file.

Comment: @MartinR He could use FileHandle also to append a string to the end of a text file. But I think he should use NSKeyedArchiever to convert his array to data and NSKeyedUnarchiever to load it from disk. I don't think he should write it to a text file

Comment: @MartinR Thanks ... This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @techno You might want to take a look at this also if you really want to store it as text https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843717/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus: It depends. If the purpose is to write a *human readable log file* then a binary archive won't help.

Comment: @MartinR if he doesn't need to convert it back to an array I agree a text file is enough

Comment: @LeoDabus  I don't want to convert it back to an array.

Comment: check the link I posted. You might think easier to use FIleHandle instead

Comment: @LeoDabus okay.Thanks

Comment: @MartinR I followed your approach.I'm getting some random characters in the output file.Please see the update.

Comment: @LeoDabus Please see the update.

Comment: @techno: You are always writing 100 bytes, regardless of the string length, therefore garbage is written. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26992040/1187415 again, it provides a `func write(_ string: String, ...)` method.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.. upon using the extension things work fine :)