# Read and write data from & to text file in Documents Directory incrementally with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, documentsdirectory

Swift 4: As you know, here is how to read or write data from & to text file in Documents Directory with Swift:

```
        let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("Test").appendingPathExtension("txt")
        print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")

        let writeString = "Add string"

        do {
            // Write to the file

            try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

        }

        var readString = "" // Used to store the file contents

        do {

            // Read the file contents

            readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

        }

        print("File Text: \(readString)")
```

It will write `Add string` to the Test.txt file.

The next time when I change `"Add string"` to `"Add some other string."`, the Test.txt file will be changed to `Add some other string.`

Which means that "Add string" will be replaced by "Add some other string.". But I would like to add these two strings to the Test.file incrementally, so that the Test.txt file will contain: Add string, Add some other string.

Is there any way to make it happen? Thanks.

Comment: You can use FIleHandle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46882118/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks a lot, Leo. That’s what I need. Really appreciate.

Comment: you are welcome