# How to write files in an iOS app to make them visible to afc protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an iOS app, and I wish to be able to copy data directly from the iOS device using a laptop.

A good example I found is Wikipedia's official iOS app (https://apps.apple.com/app/wikipedia/id324715238?mt=8). After I downloaded this app and used it for a while, I see a directory structure built in `afc://.../org.wikimedia.wikipedia` if I connect my device to a laptop running Linux. The structure is like below:

```
├── assets
│   ├── about.html
│   ├── abusefilter.css
│   ├── abusefilter.html
│   ├── bundle.js
│   ├── footer.css
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── ios.json
│   ├── languages.json
│   ├── mainpages.json
│   ├── preview.css
│   ├── preview.html
│   ├── preview.js
│   ├── styleoverrides.css
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── Wikimedia-logo.png
├── piwiktracker
├── piwiktracker-shm
├── piwiktracker-wal
├── WikipediaYap.sqlite
├── WikipediaYap.sqlite-shm
├── WikipediaYap.sqlite-wal
└── WMFHomeSections.plist
```

However, I am not able to find some **official documents** or **tutorials**, that teach me how to write a Swift program that accesses or modifies this directory. What I want to do is basically opening a text file and write some lines into it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't even supposed to access anything outside the sandbox folder assigned to your app with a proper channel.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough. I want to access this folder (maybe it is called "sandbox folder" or "Documents"?) of my own app from Swift, instead of Wikipedia's folder. But I cannot find APIs that allow me to access that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I am trying to find is the `Documents` directory in my iOS app's sandbox directory ([from documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)). 
The directory can be made visible in afc protocol by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305782),
and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26992040) gives a good example of writing to a file in that directory.